# .innerHTML issues on displaying table contents on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-table, row, innerhtml

Yes, yet another topic on problems regarding using the .innerHTML property with tables in IE (version 9, in my case, but I believe it will be the same with previous ones). After searching here and Google I found several topics regarding problems with innerHTML and IE, made some changes to my code but it still won't work in IE. As many people, I tested my code firstly with Chrome and Firefox, and it is working fine. Then I tested it on IE, the the table's contents aren't shown. I've learned through my searchings that JQuery's .html() (http://api.jquery.com/html/) may be a solution, but all my attempts have failed till now.

Basically, what I am trying to do is to randomize the appearance of the rows of a table, and the problem begins when trying to show its contents.

My code is here -> http://jsfiddle.net/jaff/BB2CF/ If someone can help me, I'll be truly grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the jQuerys's`.html()` to jQuerys's`.append()` . It works better.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Thanks Renato, I'll check that! Also, I don't know why, but the link to the code in jsFiddle was broken, so I edited original question and updated to a valid one (http://jsfiddle.net/jaff/BB2CF/).

Comment: Meanwhile, I managed to do something with .html (I must confess I'm not getting that familiar with .append()).

I managed to change the cells value with this:

`function displayRow(x, r)
{
    $("#" + x).html(r);
}`

and also (after assigning the table's ID to "questions"):

`function displayRow(x, r)
{
   $("#questions td:eq("+x+")").html(r);
}`

However, these "solutions" are only working with Chrome and Firefox, not with IE again. Does anybody has any suggestion?

Comment: It wasn't working in IE, version 8 and 9, at least. But I think I sorted it out: it wasn't from the innerHTML but from the way I was calling the function I've created (displayRow): see it for yourself -> http://jsfiddle.net/6sSA3/